# non-www to www redirect using ,htaccess

Tags: apache, redirect, seo

I want to redirect my non-www requests to www version. Have set wwww version as my preferred domain in google webmasters.
I have added the following in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But the problem is that if I hit a non-www url, it gives me 404 because of that extra space introduced automatically after the redirect. Following is a sample URL:

javaexperience.com/eclipse-get-access-modifier-suggestions-using-ucdetector-plugin/

Comment: The URL you posted worked perfectly for me.

Comment: oh! yes i am fixing it temporarily by defining a redirect rule in cPanel. Still looking for .htaccess fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rewrite rule works for me

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The rule redirects the old urls to new ones, with a 301 header, that will be ok for your SEO